# select min and max with filter grouped by day in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to optimize this query:

```
SELECT id_local, 
       id2 cardnum, 
       Date_format(paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d') date, 
       (SELECT Min(Date_format(C2.paneldate, '%H:%i:%s')) 
        FROM   doors C2 
        WHERE  C2.id2data = doors.id2data 
               AND Date_format(C2.paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = Date_format(doors.paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
               AND C2.id1data IN( 'entry1', 'entry2' )) timefistentry, 
       (SELECT Max(Date_format(C3.paneldate, '%H:%i:%s')) 
        FROM   gestionhumana.gestion_puertas C3 
        WHERE  C3.id2data = doors.id2data 
               AND Date_format(C3.paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = Date_format(doors.paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
               AND C3.id1data = 'exit1') timeexit, 
       Substring_index(id2data, '%', 1) name, 
       id1data puerta 
FROM   doors 
WHERE  Date_format(paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_sub(Curdate(), interval 4 day) 
GROUP  BY Date_format(paneldate, '%Y%m%d'), 
          id2data 
ORDER  BY paneldate DESC
```

I'm trying to get the first time a person crosses the door and the last time that crosses the exit door, they are different doors, but are recorded in the same table as different records, the query works but it takes too long. a person could cross the doors many times.

eDT. changed the name of table.
the Date_format(paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d') and (Date_format(C2.paneldate, '%H:%i:%s')  is because paneldate is datetime type, and contains the hour minutes and seconds of the registry, i cannot alter the table, and i need to groub them by days.

id_local is an id from de table
id2 is number of card
paneldate datetime of each row
id1data  name of the door (entri1,entry2,exit1)
id2data name of the  person.
 a person could have many cards, but i want get it by person and by day.

Comment: Please describe/translate your fields, it's hard to understand when the columns isn't in english

Comment: You want to avoid calling functions such as DATE_FORMAT for every row in your WHERE clauses, just compare dateA=dateB ideally.

Comment: its edited, i  translated the  fields

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my new example. It should be faster than yours (I hope).

```
SELECT
    entries.id_local,
    entries.id2 AS cardnum,
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(entries.paneldate), '%H:%i:%s') AS timefistentry,
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(exits.paneldate), '%H:%i:%s') AS timeexit,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(entries.id2data, '%', 1) AS name,
    entries.id1data AS puerta
FROM doors AS entries
LEFT JOIN (SELECT paneldate, id2data FROM doors WHERE id1data = 'exit1') AS exits ON
    entries.id2data = exits.id2data AND
    DATE_FORMAT(entries.paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(exits.paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(entries.paneldate, '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND
    entries.id1data IN( 'entry1', 'entry2' )
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(entries.paneldate, '%Y%m%d'), entries.id2data
ORDER BY entries.paneldate DESC
```

As I understand you; every time someone passes a door, the door name (id1data), the time (paneldate) and the human name (id2data) is saved on a new row. Every pass will be saved into the same table, the only thing that separates the exits from the entries is the column id1data which contains a string with the door name (exit1, entry1 and entry2).